# how can i get full iframe content in print preview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I'm loading web application inside the IFRAME. how can i get entire content in the print preview? and how can i print all content inside the iframe.?

I used simple following JavaScript function for print entire IFRAME Content by using CTRL + P. but, it's not working when i select "Print" option from the menu.

```
$(document).bind("keyup keydown", function(e)
{
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 80)
  {
    window.frames["printf"].focus();
    window.frames["printf"].print();
    return false;
  }
});
```

I need to show entire content in print preview and entire content should be printed by using "CTRL +P" and select Print in the menu. and this functionality should be working in IE, FF, Chrome.

Please give the proper solution for this issue asap.

Comment: "`It's not working`" is not a description of your problem. What happens instead? Nothing? Another iframe is printed? An error occurs? Also looks like there's something wrong with the code for the menu, why didn't you post that code?

Comment: @Teemu when you are using CTL+P, above javascript is working for get iframe content but, i need to take entire iframe content after "Print" from the browser menu.

Comment: Oh, I thought you've a menu of your own... Not possible, you can't change functionality of a browser from a web page, though you can try to focus the iframe in [`onbeforeprint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeprint) handler.

Comment: Since `onbeforeprint` is not widely supported, you might like to get familiar with [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), and get rid of the preview iframe...